# Pass an id to link_to_route inside of a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, modal-dialog

My goal is that a user has to confirm a delete operation before it's send to the controller.

At the moment I'm triggering the modal with this link:

```
<a href="#ModalDelete" class="open-Delete btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ $location->id }}">Löschen</a>
```

Inside of this modal i've put a input-field to test if my jquery is working and the id is successfully passed to it.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#Modal" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Nein, lieber doch nicht</a>
    <input id="id"></input>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-Delete", function () {
        var myId = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-footer #id").val( myId );
    });
</script>
```

Now i want to pass the id to a link_to_route function or something similar inside this modal, but don't find a way to do this.

Something like that:

```
{{ link_to_route('locations.destroy', 'Ja, Standort löschen', array($location->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
```

Is there a possibilty to do this with the link_to_route function? How do I have to pass the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way to do this. You're trying to mix dynamic JavaScript with PHP, both of which are rendered independently.

You'd be better off defining the URL for your form without the ID, using `link_to_route` or whatever solution you want, then using JavaScript to append the specific ID you want to delete to the URL, then processing it appropriately.